# date_part with composite fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to use the `date_part` function to extract a composite of multiple specifiers?

For example, I'd like to extract the month, day of month, and hour of day from a timestamp in the single string form `"month:day-of-month:hour-of-day"` so that

```
`SELECT date_part('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');`
```

would return `"02:16:20"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier with `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40', 'MM:DD:HH24')
```

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) describes the formatting options.